# How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?

Tags: c++, standards

How do you determine what version of the C++ standard is implemented by your compiler? As far as I know, below are the standards I've known:

- C++03
- C++98

Comment: I think it's a really strange question. How do I know I'm writing in English? (And a list of which compiler supports what standard is bound to go stale.)

Comment: @Mat: Well, the best answer is not a static list of compilers, but _a means of determining for yourself_ what is in use. So there you go.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Because **FAQ** stands for **Frequently Asked Question**, And this may be frequently referred or answered but this is definitely not frequently asked.

Comment: @Als: It will be soon. I promise. Besides, the `c++-faq` tag doesn't have any _actual_ pre-requisite "number of times asked" that you have to pass; it's more about the format and generality of the thing.

Comment: @Mat: Oh, balls. I don't really know what the procedure here is; I'd like to see that question updated, but I can't see how it would garner enough interest for the _answers_ to be properly updated too.

Comment: @Mat: I was hoping that this question would include specifics on how to know _which_ C++0x features your compiler supports, how to enable/disable C++11 mode, and such like. But, meh, I suppose you're probably right...

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: `c++-faq tag doesn't have any actual pre-requisite` is incorrect and you will notice that if you read the disclaimer/footer that is put with every faq question answer.

Comment: @Tomalak: detecting/turning on/off features is, IMO, a different question (no idea if/how that can be done too). That could be interesting.

Comment: @Mat: Well it's all the same thing. Detecting features _is_ akin to knowing what [parts of] standard[s] you're using. It's not cut and dry. Were I to have a reasonable answer formulated yet, I'd make the case that there is a vast grey area between the standards now, and this is only going to get worse as C++0x support widens and as C++11 permeates the homeplace.

Comment: @Als: Sorry, but I've run out of having any idea what you're talking about. [edit: OK, the `c++-faq` tag wiki covers what you're saying.]

Comment: @Tomalak I suppose this means the SO chat.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: You may want to discuss this belief of yours that there is `no actual pre-requisite "number of times asked" that you have to pass` in the C++ Lounge because the very folks who started this and the very place this was discussed mandated that a FAQ should have that pre-requisite.

Comment: sigh. title asks "used by". body asks "implemented by"... those are very different questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By my knowledge there is no overall way to do this. If you look at the headers of cross platform/multiple compiler supporting libraries you'll always find **a lot** of defines that use compiler specific constructs to determine such things:

```
/*Define Microsoft Visual C++ .NET (32-bit) compiler */
#if (defined(_M_IX86) && defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1300)
     ...
#endif

/*Define Borland 5.0 C++ (16-bit) compiler */
#if defined(__BORLANDC__) && !defined(__WIN32__)
     ...
#endif
```

You probably will have to do such defines yourself for all compilers you use.

Comment: Not my expected answer though but I guess there's just no universal way of finding it out.

Answer (score 387):

From the Bjarne Stroustrup [C++0x FAQ](//www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#11):

> #### `__cplusplus`
>
> In C++11 the macro `__cplusplus` will be set to a value that differs from (is greater than) the current `199711L`.

Although this isn't as helpful as one would like. `gcc` (apparently for nearly 10 years) had this value set to `1`, ruling out one major compiler, until [it was fixed when gcc 4.7.0 came out](//gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1773).

MSVC also doesn't set this macro correctly, to this very day. By default it's defined to `199711L` regardless of the language version, and you either need to add [`/Zc:__cplusplus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus) to compiler flags, or check a MSVC-specific macro `_MSVC_LANG` instead, which always has the right value.

These are the C++ standards and what value you should be able to expect in `__cplusplus`:

- C++ pre-C++98: `__cplusplus` is `1`.
- C++98: `__cplusplus` is `199711L`.
- C++98 + TR1: This reads as C++98 and there is no way to check that I know of.
- C++11: `__cplusplus` is `201103L`.
- C++14: `__cplusplus` is `201402L`.
- C++17: `__cplusplus` is `201703L`.
- C++20: `__cplusplus` is `202002L`.

If the compiler might be an older `gcc`, we need to resort to compiler specific hackery (look at a version macro, compare it to a table with implemented features) or use [Boost.Config](//www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) (which provides [relevant macros](//www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported)). The advantage of this is that we actually can pick specific features of the new standard, and write a workaround if the feature is missing. This is often preferred over a wholesale solution, as some compilers will claim to implement C++11, but only offer a subset of the features.

The Stdcxx Wiki hosts a [comprehensive matrix for compiler support of C++0x features (archive.org link)](//web.archive.org/web/20190528043252/https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) (if you dare to check for the features yourself).

Unfortunately, more finely-grained checking for features (e.g. individual library functions like `std::copy_if`) can only be done in the build system of your application (run code with the feature, check if it compiled and produced correct results - `autoconf` is the tool of choice if taking this route).

Comment: Doesn't look like compiler vendors are updating this - maybe they're waiting until they fully conform to the standard?(http://stackoverflow.com/q/14131454/11698)

Comment: @RichardCorden clang already defines this macro, even though the support for C++11 is partial.

Comment: @prnr: That may be true, but it's up to the user who asked the question to decide which answer to accept.  At the time that the answer which is currently marked as accepted was posted, it was correct, so the original poster accepted it.  That user could decide to change the accepted answer, but they may no longer be active on the site.

See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/is-it-possible-to-change-the-chosen-answer

Comment: The latest version of the Code::Blocks IDE (v 16.01), with MinGW, as of 12 Aug 2017, returns `201300` as the value of `__cplusplus`.

Comment: vs2017 gives __cplusplus's value 199711

Comment: Clang 4.0 is still advertising C++98. That's on Fedora 27 in 2018. Also see [Issue 35853, Clang 4.0 still uses C++98 by default](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35853)

Comment: @AlMamun Microsoft partly fixed `__cplusplus` only in VS 15.7. See their [Visual C++ Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus)

Comment: The link to the FAQ is broken.

Comment: CppReference keeps an up-to-date list of the `__cplusplus` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros.

Comment: It would be nice if the answer itself would mention `/Zc:__cplusplus` for MSVC compilers.

Answer (score 154):

Please, run the following code to check the version.

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    if (__cplusplus == 202101L) std::cout << "C++23";
    else if (__cplusplus == 202002L) std::cout << "C++20";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98";
    else std::cout << "pre-standard C++." << __cplusplus;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Its funny, because on visual studios the value of __cplusplus is 199711L and the code you posted returned c++98 however, I've used features from c++14 including variable templates and decltype(auto). Is it possible the wrong version of the macro was implemented?

Comment: See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/ (TLDR: specify the flag `/Zc:__cplusplus`)

Comment: @DaanTimmer I'm confused by that article, it seems to assume knowledge of how to use the `/Zc:__cplusplus` flag. I can't simply `std::cout << /Zc:__cplusplus;` because colons and slashes can't be part of variable names of course. Are you able to explain how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Found it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2017#to-set-this-compiler-option-in-visual-studio

Comment: I question the C++23 case, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros

Answer (score 15):

Normally you should use `__cplusplus` define to detect c++17, but by default microsoft compiler does not define that macro properly, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/ - you need to either modify project settings to include `/Zc:__cplusplus` switch, or you could use syntax like this:

```
#if ((defined(_MSVC_LANG) && _MSVC_LANG >= 201703L) || __cplusplus >= 201703L)
     //C++17 specific stuff here
#endif
```

Answer (score 9):

Depending on what you want to achieve, [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) might help you. It does not provide detection of the standard-version, but it provides macros that let you check for support of specific language/compiler-features.

Comment: Checking for features is probably a better idea than checking standard versions, anyway. Few compilers support *everything* from a standard, but if they all support the limited number of features you need, then it doesn't really matter whether the rest of the features from a given standard are implemented and working correctly.

Answer (score 6):

> __cplusplus
>
> In C++0x the macro __cplusplus will be set to a value that differs from (is greater than) the current 199711L.

[C++0x FAQ by BS](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#0x)

Answer (score 4):

Use `__cplusplus` as suggested.
Only one note for Microsoft compiler, use `Zc:__cplusplus` compiler switch to enable `__cplusplus`

Source https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `__cplusplus` (which is problematic if you are using MSVC - see most of the other answers) is feature test macros introduced in C++11.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test

I find it clearer and easier to use a specific feature test rather than checking which standard is active. It is clearer because it identifies what you really want (most standards have a lot of features and you usually don't use all of them). It is easier because often compilers only partially implement a standard so even though you are compiling with a particular standard active you might not get the feature anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After a [quick google](http://www.google.com/search?q=determine+the+c+standard+used+by+a+compiler):

`__STDC__` and `__STDC_VERSION__`, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)

Comment: Whether `__STDC__` is defined, and what its value is, are implementation-defined in C++.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, it is.
@Tor: I tried in VC++ 2005 but it says __STDC__ is an undeclared identifier. It is listed as one of those pre-defined macros though. However, __STDC_VERSION__ does not exist.

Comment: This tells you the version of the C programming language supported by the compiler. It tells you nothing about the version of the C++ language that is supported.

Answer (score 0):

For cmake projects can use:

```
if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(mytarget PUBLIC "/Zc:__cplusplus")
endif()
```

Font: https://peter-bloomfield-online.translate.goog/report-__cplusplus-correctly-with-cmake-and-visual-studio/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=pt&_x_tr_hl=pt-BR&_x_tr_pto=sc