# How can you tell which version of the ISO C++ standard your compiler supports?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

Is there a way for your program to determine this at compile time? Are there preprocessor macros you can use?

I know that g++ has this [nice matrix of c++0x/c++11 feature support](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). Does this exist for other popular compilers? Are there any standard (de facto or otherwise) ways to use the preprocessor to test for the existence of a given feature?

There is a question about this, but the answers do not seem very complete: [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

I know Boost.Config does this, but how does it do it? It might be nice to know if I don't want to use Boost for whatever reason.

I'm closing this as a duplicate because someone edited one of the [answers in the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler/7132549#7132549) to be much more complete.

Comment: @Bo Persson - I'm tempted to delete this question myself in frustration. That question has no answers that are particularly useful. Heck, I found a more useful answer in a g++ bug report than in that question. And nobody is bothering with any decent answers here either.

Comment: @Omnifarious - I've added a link to a feature matrix, similar to the one boost will be using for boost.config.

Comment: I don't think there is any language standard answers, just compiler manuals documenting the amount of C++11 support. The committee specifically rejected the idea of having macros for partial implementations. They want compilers to implement the whole language!

Comment: Ahaha.. [third time today...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

Comment: @Tomalak - with the press generated by the C++0x vote it might well not be the last...

Comment: @Omnifarious I tried making my answer to the proposed dup as comprehensive as possible. Unfortunately checking for features in a static language is messy.

Comment: @pmr - I'll close it as a dup then, though I'm going to edit in my bit about what values of `__cplusplus` mean what.

Comment: @awoodland: I'm certain that it won't be. That's why I was trying to start a comprehensive post on the issue, but I failed. :(

Comment: @Tomalak: Where is your question? I find neither this question, nor the question linked to to have particularly satisfactory answers. I realize it's not an easy problem, but it would be nice to have more details on particular compilers and things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the value of `__cplusplus`

> In C++0x the macro __cplusplus will be set to a value that differs
>   from (is greater than) the current 199711L.

[http://predef.sf.net](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Standards) has some values for detecting specific standards.

The [Boost.Config recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler/2324913#2324913) on the question you linked to is good advice too, and offers a more fine-grained answer. I think it basically codifies a [feature matrix](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) and periodically updates it.

Comment: Which values correspond to which standards?

Comment: And, as a practical matter (and this is a bug in g++) g++ defines this macro to be `1` even if you specify `-std=c++0x` on the command line.

Comment: that may be an acknowledgement that their support is incomplete. It makes Boost.Config all the more valuable though.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport has a useful feature matrix too.

Comment: The Apache wiki is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: If you're prepared to do it at configure instead of build time there's a few relevant ones at https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/The-Macros.html and I'm sure CMake has equivalent too. Doing it that way at least has the advantage that it reduces the maintenance burdens of a feature matrix approach.

Comment: @pmr - That is true. Unfortunately I can't get 4.7.0 unless I'm willing to compile a snapshot of an unstable tree, or directly from a Subversion repository. :-/

Comment: @Omnifarius So, you really are out of options. Boost.Config is basically the only way you can do this. Ah, btw there is a nice matrix for major compilers here: https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

Answer (score 1):

To jump start this in the direction I was hoping it would go, here is some useful information I gleaned from a [g++ bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1773).

- C++ pre-C++98: `__cplusplus` is `1`.
- C++98: `__cplusplus` is `199711L`.
- C++0x/11: `__cplusplus` is `201103L`.