# How to assert that C++11 should be used to compile my program?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to use some C++11 features in my program. I might have to share my source code with others in future. **How do I assert, inside the code, that C++11 should be used to compile my program?** An older compiler might throw an error, but I want the user to be informed clearly that C++11 is required.

I'm using the following C++11 features, if that matters:

- enum with storage size specified
- std shared pointer

thanks

Comment: `static_assert(true);`. (I'm joking.  Don't do this.)

Comment: Be aware that at time of writing, there is no compiler that fully supports C++11. So if you test for complete C++11 support, you'll have a lot of false negatives -- compilers that have the features you need but which don't implement C++11 and so are rejected by your test.

Comment: @SteveJessop I had the impression that GCC already supports all of the C++11 features according to [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport). If I'm wrong, please, correct me.

Comment: @Malcolm They support the majority of them, but some details can be perfected and the libstdc++ is not not fully C++11-compliant.

Comment: @Malcolm: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x. Lots of progress, but still some significant omissions.

Comment: Time to explore `cmake`.

Comment: @Dilawar Moved to Scons years ago. For a comparison between cmake, Scons and other such tools: https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/SconsVsOtherBuildTools

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could check that the value of the `__cplusplus` macro is `201103L` or greater:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error This code requires C++11
#endif
```

C++11 16.8 Predeﬁned macro names:

> The following macro names shall be deﬁned by the implementation:
>
> `__cplusplus`
>
> **The name `__cplusplus` is deﬁned to the value `201103L`** when compiling a C++ translation unit. (155)
>
> (155) It is intended that future versions of this standard will replace the value of this macro with a greater value. Non-conforming
> compilers should use a value with at most ﬁve decimal digits.

Comment: Should I use something like #if _cplusplus == 201103L {my code} #elif {display error} ?

Comment: @NehaKaranjkar: Don't compare for the equality. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I just learned about the #error directive. Thanks. +1 to both answers mentioning this.

Comment: `__cplusplus` is broken on Windows, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131454/visual-studio-2012-cplusplus-and-c-11

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Agreed.  Since VS 2012 doesn't even support C++98 (much less C++11), the value should be a 5 digit number.  (Supporting one or two odd features from C++11 doesn't mean that you support C++11.)

Comment: Likewise, all those C++98 compilers that didn't support `export` shouldn't have set it to `199711L`, although some did. There's a practical problem with the value of the `__cplusplus` macro, which is that it's not designed to help tell the difference between a compiler that doesn't conform to C++98, and a compiler that doesn't conform to C++11 ;-)

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.6.3 with the -std=C++0x flag, and the check for __cplusplus < 201103L fails. So does the check for 199711L. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Neha See my answer below: before GCC 4.7, `__cplusplus` is set to 1 for `-std=c++0x`. That's why you should consider using `Boost.Config` for the check.

Answer (score 9):

[__cplusplus](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#11) macro may come handy

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error C++11 Required
#endif
```

Something like this

Comment: The example structure works, but I'd go for checking less than the C++11 value.

Comment: @rhalbersma: I agree with the technicality of your observation though I really don't think another ratification is happening any time soon. C++03 ---> C++11, 8 years ha..

Comment: It will have greater date and expected to be backward compatible with c++11

Comment: @AlokSave, Last I heard, C++14 was well on its way. A year or so ago, people decided they would get cracking on moving C++ forward faster.

Comment: @chris yes  Bjarne Stroustrup seemed to have outdated FAQ.

Comment: @chris: How long did we hear similar rumors about C++11, i really doubt those.

Comment: @alexrider, It was written before C++11 came out. You can easily tell be the fact that he says it *will* be set.

Comment: @AlokSave, You must have seen http://isocpp.org/ by now. Fact is that concepts were actually delayed until C++17 because there wasn't enough time to get it all ready in time for C++14. Instead, they're trying to at least get the constraints part in.

Comment: @AlokSave 100+ papers for the upcoming Bristol committee meeting. the pace of development is very high, but of course standardization might be considerably smaller in scope

Comment: @rhalbersma: if you're concerned about future backward-incompatibilities then you can test for exact equality. And that is a valid concern, for example in N3424 Herb Sutter calls for a breaking change in respect of lambdas ASAP. In fact, implementations of any future versions of the standard are pretty well *guaranteed* not to conform to the C++11 standard. Even if no syntax or semantics are changed, they will have a different value of `__cplusplus` and thus not conform to C++11. So it is not intended that any major release of the standard is truly compatible, although corrigenda might be.

Answer (score 5):

As it has already been said, the correct solution would be to check for the `__cplusplus` macro. However, some compilers have a partial support for C++11 features but do not set this macro for the correct value. For example, strongly-typed enumerations are available in g++ since GCC 4.4.0. However, with the option `-std=c++11` (and its equivalents), the macro `__cplusplus` was not set to the good value before GCC 4.7.0 (it was set to 1 instead). That means that some compilers can compile your code but won't if you check for C++11 that way.

If you just need specific features, then I would check for them with [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) which defines [a whole set of macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported) that can be used to check whther your compiler supports the required features. In your case, you would need:

- `BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS` for strongly-typed enumerations.
- `BOOST_NO_CXX11_SMART_PTR` for `std::shared_ptr`.