# No C++11 on vs 2015 pro?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 RC Pro because I wanted to use c++11's std::to_string but it still doesn't seem to be 11...

```
std::cout << _cplusplus << std::endl;
```

Gives me 199711.
Is VS 2015 RC not supposed to have 11? Or am I doing something wrong?
Help appreciated.

Edit: it seems it isn't extremely clear what I want, so here's more info:

I want to use to_string, a member of std in c++11 which turns an int (in this case) into a string.

```
std::to_string(5);
```

gives me an error: *"std has no member to_string"*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 \_\_cplusplus and C++ 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131454/visual-studio-2012-cplusplus-and-c-11)

Comment: VS2015 provides an nearly complete implementation of C++11, see e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx

Comment: Yeah but I don't seem to have 11 at all? Edit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx

Comment: Please check the SO question (and the answers) from my first comment. VS seems not to use the _cplusplus macro correctly, despite having implemented (most of) C++11.

Comment: But I don't care about the macro, I don't intend to use it. I only want std::to_string and it isn't there. I'm pretty sure C++11 is not implemented at all. And if it is, how can I get std::to_string to work?

Comment: Then please make your question more clear. std::to_string() is available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee404875.aspx

Comment: Maybe provide a short code sample which does not work.

Comment: You have included the header <string>?

Comment: Oh my God, i'm am retarded. I've been searching for this for hours and hours and I din't include the string header...Thanks dude

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include the header `<string>`

Answer (score 2):

VS2015 still doesn't fully support C++11, so the __cplusplus macro will remain as 97.