# How to enable c++14 in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 with c++98. I found out by doing this:

```
cout << __cplusplus;
```

that showed me "199711L" , but I want to use features that are specific to c++14.
(I know that there are reasons why __cplusplus is shwing this(according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131454/visual-studio-2012-cplusplus-and-c-11)) and I have access to some features of c++11 like smart pointers)

VS has c++11 by default, but how can I enable c++14 for example??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 \_\_cplusplus and C++ 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131454/visual-studio-2012-cplusplus-and-c-11) - it would appear to be a bug/feature that that value is  apparently out of date. C++11 should work by default.

Comment: You can't.  VS2012 was not yet fully C++11 compliant and certainly couldn't know what would happen in 2014.  They had to do a lot of work on the front-end to make it compliant, in fact completely rewrite it, that work wasn't completed until VS2015.  What you can depend on is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).