# Can't set c++ version in CMake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to set the C++ version to 11 with cmake, but despite trying multiple methods it just doesn't seem to do anything. I've reduce the issue down to 2 files:
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
project(test)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} test.cpp)
```

test.cpp

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error not c++ 11
#endif
```

I'm running CMake version `3.17.20032601-MSVC_2`, from the CMake extension in visual studio code.

Comment: And what is your compiler?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51303151/10871073) in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Textbook example of not narrowing down a problem ... ;)

Comment: @AdrianMole i've read over it and this macro is being used in the libraries i need to use for my project, so i can't do much about it unless i were to go over all the files and manually fix any issues

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings i think it's visual studio community 2019 - amd64

Comment: @SArpnt If you read the linked answer, you'll find that you can solve the problem with a simple flag...