# Is there a system task or pre-processor directive in SystemVerilog for retrieving the used standard version?

Tags: version, system-verilog, preprocessor-directive

I implemented a SV module which contains soft constraints. However, as far as I know soft constraints are only supported since 1800-2012 standard. Therefore I would like to add an alternative implementation  in case a simulator is used that only supports older standard versions.
Is there a way to retrieve this information with a system task or pre-processor directive in such a way:

```
if($get_version_specifier == "1800-2012")
   // do fancy stuff with soft constraints
else
   // alternative fancy stuff
```

I already found an option for a similar problem by using `begin_keywords`, `end_keywords`, but I think that would not solve my issue since it only defines the set of keywords for a specific standard. And if the simulator does not support this version I guess only an error would occur.

Thanks in advance!
sebs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you ask about is more complicated than it seems. Different features of SystemVerilog are implemented by different versions of tool; sometimes before the standard is released, sometimes after. I do know that some tools supported **soft constraints** before the release of the 1800-2012 standard, and no commercial tool that I know of has yet to support **operator overloading**, which was in the first IEEE 1800-2005 standard.

A better solution would be to define a set of macros like `USE_SOFT_CONSTRAINTS` for features that do not have universal support. Then you can include a common featureset.svh file that defines the feature set you want to use. Another good practice is to **DOCUMENT** the reason you added a specific feature macro (*i.e the tool version you were using that didn't support the feature and why you decided it was worth the effort to implement both branches of the code*).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't any "standard" way of getting the version of the standard you are using. C++ had a similar problem before the 2011 release (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)). One answer there states that different compilers added different proprietary defines (something like the `INCA` macro set for the Incisive simulator). You'll have to ask your simulator vendor if a define for the version of the SV standard exists (something like `SV2012_OR_GREATER`).

Cadence, for example, has something like this for Specman, so if they're consistent they might have this for SystemVerilog as well. Assuming such a thing exists, you could have:

```
`ifdef SV_2012_OR_GREATER
  // do fancy stuff with soft constraints
`else
  // alternative fancy stuff
`endif
```

Bonus: Soft constraints are a declarative construct, so I don't see how you could use an `if` block to decide whether to use them or not (unless maybe if it's an `if` inside a constraint block). Also, I'm not sure whether you're able to truly emulate soft constraints in any way, however fancy your approach is, so I don't know if it really makes sense to try.

Comment: You probably could emulate a soft constraint by calling randomize(), and checking the result. If it returns 0 (i.e. it has failed to randomize), then you turn off your "soft constraint" and call randomize() again.

Comment: @stan Yeah, but how do you know if the randomize failed because that constraint and not another?

Comment: The setup will break if your randomizations can fail for other reasons, for sure. But in most cases, you don't expect the randomization to fail unless something went wrong.