# How to check the C++ version is being used in Linux OS?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, boost, g++

I have tried to print:

```
std::cout << __cplusplus;
```

And Getting 1 as output.

Also I have tried: `g++ -version` command. It produces the output:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How to determine the version of the C++ standard with the above output ??

Or Is there any other way ??

Somewhere I found like, *Boost.Config has a plethora of macros that can be used to test for support for specific C++11 features.*

Comment: Version of what? Compiler, Libraries, c++ standard, c++ features?

Comment: version of the standard for the programming language C++ @Klaus

Comment: I added the c++version check in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have tried to print:
>
> ```
> std::cout << __cplusplus;
> ```
>
> And Getting 1 as output

It sounds like `__cplusplus` is being coerced into a `bool`. You should probably show the full code, and not the abridged snippet.

Maybe you can cast `__cplusplus` to an `unsigned` type. Or maybe you need to include a c++ header like `<iostream>`. However, I cannot reproduce your results when doing so:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
    std::cout << (unsigned int)__cplusplus << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

$ ./test.exe
201402
201402
```

---

> How to determine the version with the above output ?? Or Is there any other way ??

Usually you ask the compiler to give them to you. Also see the output of `echo '#include <iostream>' | g++ -x c++ -dM -E - | sort`. The one below is from Fedora 25 with GCC 6.3.

You can get even more macros tuned for the particular CPU you have by adding `-march=native`. Then you will see preprocessor definitions like `__AES__`, `__PCLMUL__`, `__SHA__`, etc.

You can also use different versions of the C++ standard with `-std=c++03`, `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14`, etc.

```
$ echo '#include <iostream>' | g++ -x c++ -dM -E - | sort
#define ADJ_ESTERROR 0x0008
#define ADJ_FREQUENCY 0x0002
#define ADJ_MAXERROR 0x0004
#define ADJ_MICRO 0x1000
#define ADJ_NANO 0x2000
#define ADJ_OFFSET 0x0001
#define ADJ_OFFSET_SINGLESHOT 0x8001
#define ADJ_OFFSET_SS_READ 0xa001
#define ADJ_SETOFFSET 0x0100
#define ADJ_STATUS 0x0010
#define ADJ_TAI 0x0080
#define ADJ_TICK 0x4000
#define ADJ_TIMECONST 0x0020
#define _ALLOCA_H 1
#define alloca(size) __builtin_alloca (size)
#define _ALLOCATOR_H 1
#define _ALLOC_TRAITS_H 1
#define __always_inline __inline __attribute__ ((__always_inline__))
#define __amd64 1
#define __amd64__ 1
#define _ANSI_STDDEF_H
#define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H
#define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_H
#define __ASMNAME2(prefix,cname) __STRING (prefix) cname
#define __ASMNAME(cname) __ASMNAME2 (__USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, cname)
#define _ATFILE_SOURCE 1
#define __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL 4
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
#define __ATOMIC_CONSUME 1
#define __ATOMIC_HLE_ACQUIRE 65536
#define __ATOMIC_HLE_RELEASE 131072
#define __ATOMIC_RELAXED 0
#define __ATOMIC_RELEASE 3
#define __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST 5
...
#define _T_PTRDIFF
#define _T_PTRDIFF_
#define __try try
#define _T_SIZE
#define _T_SIZE_
#define _T_WCHAR
#define _T_WCHAR_
#define _TYPEINFO
#define __U16_TYPE unsigned short int
#define __U32_TYPE unsigned int
#define __U64_TYPE unsigned long int
#define __u_char_defined
#define __uid_t_defined
#define __UID_T_TYPE __U32_TYPE
#define __UINT16_C(c) c
#define UINT16_C(c) c
#define __UINT16_MAX__ 0xffff
#define UINT16_MAX (65535)
#define __UINT16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define UINT16_WIDTH 16
#define __UINT32_C(c) c ## U
#define UINT32_C(c) c ## U
#define __UINT32_MAX__ 0xffffffffU
#define UINT32_MAX (4294967295U)
#define __uint32_t_defined
#define __UINT32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define UINT32_WIDTH 32
#define __UINT64_C(c) c ## UL
#define UINT64_C(c) c ## UL
#define __UINT64_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define UINT64_MAX (__UINT64_C(18446744073709551615))
#define __UINT64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define UINT64_WIDTH 64
#define __UINT8_C(c) c
#define UINT8_C(c) c
#define __UINT8_MAX__ 0xff
#define UINT8_MAX (255)
#define __UINT8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define UINT8_WIDTH 8
#define __UINT_FAST16_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define UINT_FAST16_MAX (18446744073709551615UL)
#define __UINT_FAST16_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define UINT_FAST16_WIDTH __WORDSIZE
#define __UINT_FAST32_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define UINT_FAST32_MAX (18446744073709551615UL)
#define __UINT_FAST32_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define UINT_FAST32_WIDTH __WORDSIZE
#define __UINT_FAST64_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define UINT_FAST64_MAX (__UINT64_C(18446744073709551615))
#define __UINT_FAST64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define UINT_FAST64_WIDTH 64
#define __UINT_FAST8_MAX__ 0xff
#define UINT_FAST8_MAX (255)
#define __UINT_FAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define UINT_FAST8_WIDTH 8
#define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0xffff
#define UINT_LEAST16_MAX (65535)
#define __UINT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define UINT_LEAST16_WIDTH 16
#define __UINT_LEAST32_MAX__ 0xffffffffU
#define UINT_LEAST32_MAX (4294967295U)
#define __UINT_LEAST32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define UINT_LEAST32_WIDTH 32
#define __UINT_LEAST64_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define UINT_LEAST64_MAX (__UINT64_C(18446744073709551615))
#define __UINT_LEAST64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define UINT_LEAST64_WIDTH 64
#define __UINT_LEAST8_MAX__ 0xff
#define UINT_LEAST8_MAX (255)
#define __UINT_LEAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define UINT_LEAST8_WIDTH 8
#define __UINTMAX_C(c) c ## UL
#define UINTMAX_C(c) c ## UL
#define __UINTMAX_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define UINTMAX_MAX (__UINT64_C(18446744073709551615))
#define __UINTMAX_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define UINTMAX_WIDTH 64
#define __u_intN_t(N,MODE) typedef unsigned int u_int ##N ##_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (MODE)))
#define __UINTPTR_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define UINTPTR_MAX (18446744073709551615UL)
#define __UINTPTR_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define UINTPTR_WIDTH __WORDSIZE
#define __ULONG32_TYPE unsigned int
#define __ULONGWORD_TYPE unsigned long int
#define __unix 1
#define __unix__ 1
#define unix 1
#define __UQUAD_TYPE unsigned long int
#define __USE_ATFILE 1
#define __useconds_t_defined
#define __USECONDS_T_TYPE __U32_TYPE
#define __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL 0
#define __USE_GNU 1
#define __USE_ISOC11 1
#define __USE_ISOC95 1
#define __USE_ISOC99 1
#define __USE_ISOCXX11 1
#define __USE_LARGEFILE 1
#define __USE_LARGEFILE64 1
#define __USE_MISC 1
#define __USE_POSIX 1
#define __USE_POSIX199309 1
#define __USE_POSIX199506 1
#define __USE_POSIX2 1
#define __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__
#define __USE_UNIX98 1
#define __USE_XOPEN 1
#define __USE_XOPEN2K 1
#define __USE_XOPEN2K8 1
#define __USE_XOPEN2K8XSI 1
#define __USE_XOPEN2KXSI 1
#define __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED 1
#define __USING_NAMESPACE_C99(name)
#define __USING_NAMESPACE_STD(name)
#define __UWORD_TYPE unsigned long int
#define __va_arg_pack() __builtin_va_arg_pack ()
#define __va_arg_pack_len() __builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()
#define _VA_LIST_DEFINED
#define __VERSION__ "7.1.1 20170622 (Red Hat 7.1.1-3)"
#define __WALL 0x40000000
#define __warnattr(msg) __attribute__((__warning__ (msg)))
#define __warndecl(name,msg) extern void name (void) __attribute__((__warning__ (msg)))
#define _WCHAR_H 1
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __WCHAR_MAX __WCHAR_MAX__
#define WCHAR_MAX __WCHAR_MAX
#define __WCHAR_MIN__ (-__WCHAR_MAX__ - 1)
#define __WCHAR_MIN __WCHAR_MIN__
#define WCHAR_MIN __WCHAR_MIN
#define __wchar_t__
#define __WCHAR_T
#define __WCHAR_T__
#define _WCHAR_T
#define _WCHAR_T_
#define _WCHAR_T_DECLARED
#define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED_
#define _WCHAR_T_H
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __WCHAR_WIDTH__ 32
#define WCHAR_WIDTH 32
#define __WCLONE 0x80000000
#define __W_CONTINUED 0xffff
#define WCONTINUED 8
#define __WCOREDUMP(status) ((status) & __WCOREFLAG)
#define __WCOREFLAG 0x80
#define _WCTYPE_H 1
#define WEOF (0xffffffffu)
#define __W_EXITCODE(ret,sig) ((ret) << 8 | (sig))
#define WEXITED 4
#define __WEXITSTATUS(status) (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)
#define WEXITSTATUS(status) __WEXITSTATUS (status)
#define __WIFCONTINUED(status) ((status) == __W_CONTINUED)
#define WIFCONTINUED(status) __WIFCONTINUED (status)
#define WIFEXITED(status) __WIFEXITED (status)
#define __WIFEXITED(status) (__WTERMSIG(status) == 0)
#define __WIFSIGNALED(status) (((signed char) (((status) & 0x7f) + 1) >> 1) > 0)
#define WIFSIGNALED(status) __WIFSIGNALED (status)
#define __WIFSTOPPED(status) (((status) & 0xff) == 0x7f)
#define WIFSTOPPED(status) __WIFSTOPPED (status)
#define __WINT_MAX__ 0xffffffffU
#define WINT_MAX (4294967295u)
#define WINT_MIN (0u)
#define __WINT_MIN__ 0U
#define _WINT_T
#define __WINT_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __WINT_WIDTH__ 32
#define WINT_WIDTH 32
#define WNOHANG 1
#define __WNOTHREAD 0x20000000
#define WNOWAIT 0x01000000
#define __WORDSIZE 64
#define __WORDSIZE_TIME64_COMPAT32 1
#define __W_STOPCODE(sig) ((sig) << 8 | 0x7f)
#define WSTOPPED 2
#define __WSTOPSIG(status) __WEXITSTATUS(status)
#define WSTOPSIG(status) __WSTOPSIG (status)
#define __WTERMSIG(status) ((status) & 0x7f)
#define WTERMSIG(status) __WTERMSIG (status)
#define WUNTRACED 2
#define __wur
#define __x86_64 1
#define __x86_64__ 1
#define _XLOCALE_H 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want specific features in c++, you can use the macros described here:
e.g. you want to know if lib chrono is available: `__cpp_lib_chrono` contains a value `201510`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros

The version of the used c++ standard can be checked by: `__cplusplus`. For c++17 the value is "201703", for c++14 it is "201402". But also if the compiler seems to have c++14 enabled, you should keep in mind that not all features must be present. For specific features you can check the macros above. This specific part of the question has already an answer here:
[How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

gcc for example have also predefined macros to check e.g. `:__GNUC__`

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

It is somewhat unclear if you want to check during compile time or before, like in configure step.

If you want to know something in configure step, you can write small test progs which test for the above described macros and write the result to stdout so you can check in gmake or autotools.

Also you can check things in Makefile and share that info with your compiler by defining macros with `-D` flag.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried to print:
>
> ```
> std::cout << __cplusplus;
> ```
>
> And Getting 1 as output

This is expected behavior for `g++ 4.4.7`, according to [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

> gcc (apparently for nearly 10 years) had this value set to 1 ... until it was fixed when gcc 4.7.0 came out.

An alternative solution would be to keep your `__cplusplus` approach and upgrade to `g++ 4.7.0` or higher.