# Is there a #define for the C++ version being compiled?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, c++14

As in the title,

is there a C++ preprocessor `#define` that defines the C++ version being compiled? Like a compile with `clang++ -std=c++11` produces a define `__CPP_VERSION` or whatever.

The possible duplicate at [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler) is inaccurate.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace says that C++ defines a `__cplusplus` preprocessor macro with a specific number for a given C++ version.

Comment: In practice you have a problem when a compiler implements 99.9% of C++xx, but one feature is missing. What should the defined value be? Does your code *really care* if [reference_wrapper is trivially copyable](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4277.html)?