# What is the default C++ standard in an Eclipse CDT project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT 3.8.1 with GCC Cross Compiler 8.6.0. I know how to change the C++ standard in the project properties, but I don't know what standard is used by default.

I know the default is not C++11 and the Eclipse language support page doesn't mention C++03, so I suspect the default is C++98. However, Eclipse CDT must support C++03 because adding the compiler flag -std=c++03 doesn't cause any errors.
https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/april/article3.php

What is the default standard when I create a new project?

Comment: May be a dup of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler

Comment: "what standard is used by default" - depends on your compiler version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's parser itself doesn't have a notion of a C++ standard mode. It will recognize all the C++ features that have been implemented in its parser (which, as of writing this, is all C++98 and C++11 features, some (but not all) C++14 features, and a handful of C++17 features).

However, standard library headers often contain sections that are conditional on macros denoting the C++ standard version (e.g. `#if __cplusplus >= 201103` is a common check for "C++11 or later"). To determine the value of these macros, Eclipse invokes the compiler specified in the project's toolchain to discover built-in macros. The discovered value of e.g. the `__cplusplus` macro will depend on what standards mode the *compiler* runs in for this invocation.

The flags to this compiler invocation are specified in the project properties, as you mentioned. If you don't provide a flag there, the compiler will use whatever its default mode is. I believe GCC has been using `-std=c++14` as the default from GCC 6 onwards. (Though I don't quite know what "GCC Cross Compiler 8.6.0" is. According to the [GCC website](https://gcc.gnu.org/), the latest version is 8.1.)

Comment: I think the default flag is actually `-std=gnu++14` or something like that. Basically C++ 14 with non-standard extensions.

Comment: I am using gcc 5.4.0. __cplusplus = 199711L with my current setup.

Comment: @RickD. That would be C++98 then. Note that C++03 is a very minor revision of C++98, with no notable new features. C++98 and C++03 are often used interchangeably.