# Is '_HAS_CXX17' macro usable in custom project headers to enable C++17 language set features?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, boost-optional, stdoptional

I want to create headers which use 'optional' from standard C++.
However, My headers will be referred from Visual Studio 2015 as well as Visual Studio 2017 projects.

I would like to have something, such that for Visual Studio 2017 ( with C++ 17 lang feature set) , std::optional is used and with Visual Studio 2015, boost::optional gets used.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
#include <yvals.h>
#if _HAS_CXX17
 #include <optional>
 template <typename T> using Optional = std::optional<T>;
#else
 #include "boost/optional/optional.hpp"
 template <typename T> using Optional = boost::optional<T>;
#endif
```

Is it okay to use '_HAS_CXX17' macro this way? 
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

Comment: Consider using `__has_include(<optional>)` and `__has_include(<experimental/optional>)` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include). Some compilers / standard libraries offer the library features before the actual standard is used.

Comment: @Justin given that `__has_include` was added in  C++17, using it to detect specific C++17 features sounds problematic.

Comment: @Sneftel Not exactly. You do an `#ifdef __has_include`, then use `__has_include` normally

Comment: See also the [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test)

Comment: @Justin.. I do not only want the header inclusion, but also the feature inclusion.... just using __has_include will not suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: **No** It's not safe to rely on internal preprocessor defines in the implementation of the Visual C++ Runtime, and technically all compiler symbols that begin with a single `_` are reserved for use by the implementation.

For example, `_NOEXCEPT` has been used internally in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, but as of VS 2017 (15.8 update), this macro no longer exists; the headers just use `noexcept` directly.

The recommendation to use `__has_include` is good, but isn't supported prior to VS 2017 (15.3 update).

The other challenge is that `__cplusplus` doesn't indicate you are using `/std:c++17` unless you are using VS 2017 (15.7 update) with the new `/Zc:__cplusplus` switch which is off by default.

Probably the safest way to do this across a range of VS versions would be:

```
#if (__cplusplus >= 201703L) || (defined(_MSVC_LANG) && (_MSVC_LANG >= 201703L) && (_MSC_VER >= 1913))
#if __has_include(<optional>)
 #include <optional>
 template <typename T> using Optional = std::optional<T>;
#else
 #include "boost/optional/optional.hpp"
 template <typename T> using Optional = boost::optional<T>;
#endif
#else
 #include "boost/optional/optional.hpp"
 template <typename T> using Optional = boost::optional<T>;
#endif
```

> See [Visual C++ Language Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance)

Comment: Does MSVC define the [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test)?

Comment: To be fair, the committee didn't define the feature test macros until C++20 :( See [P0096r5](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0096r5.html)

Comment: Thank you @ChuckWalbourn. One thing that concerns me is if we have checked for _MSVC_LANG >= 201703L, then why do we need to check for _MSC_VER?

Comment: The ``_MSVC_LANG >= 201703L`` test tells out it's Microsoft Visual C++ with ``/std:c++17`` or ``/std:c++latest`` without ``/Zc:__cplusplus``. You still need to make sure it's VS 2017 (15.3 update) or later before you try to use ``__has_include``. In the case where ``__cplusplus >= 201703L``, then it's VS 2017 (15.7 update) or later already with ``/Zc:__cplusplus`` or some other C++17 Standard compiler.