# VS2019 not selecting C++17 despite project settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I'm running VS2019 v16.6.2

I have been following the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256738/visual-studio-2019-c-and-stdfilesystem) question on how to set VS2019 to C++17 and define "ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)" as the source language. However, the compiler is not using C++17 standard. I wrote the following test program to see the compilers settings. Output follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem> // C++17 standard header file name

int main() {

#if !_HAS_CXX17
    printf("No C17");
#endif

    printf("\n%i", _MSVC_LANG);
    printf("\n%i", _HAS_CXX17);

    printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
No C++17
201402
0

Press any key to exit.
```

What am I missing to set the language standard? I need to use c17 because I want to use the filesystem library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is '\_HAS\_CXX17' marco usable in custom project headers to enable C++17 language set features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379233/is-has-cxx17-marco-usable-in-custom-project-headers-to-enable-c17-language)

Comment: I don't think so, but it did point me to the __cplusplus value. In my case here it's 199711. Another pointer to my version of VS not listening to its settings.

Comment: Did you try adding the `/Zc:__cplusplus` switch to your settings?

Comment: Yes. I added /Zc:__cplusplus as an additional switch to the cli arguments in the project properties.

Comment: Works just fine as posted.  Use Project > Properties and pay attention to the two comboboxes at the top of the dialog.  You need to make sure that "All Configurations" and "All Platforms" are selected.

Comment: C++17’s <filesystem> is supported. This is a completely new implementation, incompatible with the previous std::experimental version, necessitated by symlink support, bug fixes, and changes in standard-required behavior. Currently, including <filesystem> provides the new std::filesystem and the previous std::experimental::filesystem, and including <experimental/filesystem> provides only the old experimental implementation. The experimental implementation will be REMOVED in the next ABI-breaking release of the libraries.

Comment: I set the properties and tested this code. It worked fine. So, I think it may be because the property platform setting and the running platform setting are inconsistent. You could check whether `Debug/Release` in `Properties` is the same as `Debug/Release` in `Solutions Configurations`.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Thanks, I forgot to check the Configuration titles. :/ That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When editing the project properties, make sure:

- **Configuration** is set to **All Configurations**, and
- **Platform** is set to **All Platforms**.

Otherwise your changes may not be applied to your currently active build configuration and platform.

(I had the OP's exact problem but it took me 2 visits to this question before I realized the solution was buried in the comments.)