# Conditionally compile function if `std::optional` exists

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I am having a mixed C++14/C++17 codebase and I want to enable a function `isEmpty` only if I am having `std::optional` at hand. So, I tried SFINAE:

```
template <typename T, typename int_<decltype(std::nullopt)>::type = 0>
inline bool isEmpty(const std::optional<T>& v) {
  return !v;
}
```

However, that doesn't work.

How can I conditionally compile `isEmpty` if `std::optional` is there?

Comment: Normally you wrap this in a check using the preprocessor for the presence of the C++17 language flag: `#ifdef c++17_flag your_code #endif`

Comment: You can find the flags here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483887/4342498

Comment: Ah, the oft misunderstood sfinae. It is not for conditional compilation, but for pruning overloads in overload resolution. You can't just put a token soup there an expect it to work.

Comment: what is `int_` ?

Comment: Related, for Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379233/is-has-cxx17-macro-usable-in-custom-project-headers-to-enable-c17-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler is recent enough (e.g. GCC >= 9.1 or Clang >= 9.0.0), you may include header [`<version>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/version) and conditionally compile your function template if macro [`__cpp_lib_optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test#Library_features) is defined:

```
#include <version> // provides, among others, __cpp_lib_optional

#ifdef __cpp_lib_optional
template <typename T>
inline bool isEmpty(const std::optional<T>& v) {
    return !v;
}
#endif
```

This way, `isEmpty` will only be compiled if you're in `-std=c++17` mode (or higher).

Comment: For Visual Studio this would be `#if  _HAS_CXX17`.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap `#include <optional>` inside a conditional block, too. Either inside the shown `#ifdef __cpp_lib_optional` block, or inside of its own `#ifdef __has_header #if __has_header(<optional>) #include <optional> #endif #endif` block