# How to check whether a library can be compiled by a specific g++ version?

Tags: c++, g++

I was doing a c++ homework which would be compiled with g++4.4.7, but I have some downgrade problem, so I decided to compile it with higher g++ version, but I don't know what library can be used in g++4.4.7, are there any document I can check?

By the way, can `vector` be included in `g++ 4.4.7` ?

Comment: Only by trying to compile it. You don't need to downgrade, you can install any version of gcc (or a dozen) alongside your system version.

Comment: It *shouldn't* really depend on compiler version, but on C++ standard that you use (`-std=` flag). Note that different compiler versions may have different default standard version, you may want to limit yourself to `c++03` if you are not sure what falgs are used at that `g++4.4.7` compiler

Comment: One more note: `c++03` is the default option for g++ versions lower than 6.1, for 6.1 and up the default is `c++14` (or to be precise, the respective standard versions with GNU additions, so respectively `gnu++03` and `gnu++14`)

Comment: It's more of a matter of what standard your class uses.  If you need to compile against C++03 (no auto, smart pointers, variadic templates, ...) then you just need to make sure you specify `-std=c++03` when you compile.  If not then you can use `-std=c++11` as gcc 4 started experimental support for C++11.  More than likely the C++03 version is what your class requires.

Comment: "By the way, can vector be included in g++ 4.4.7 ?" - `std::vector` has existed since C++98. Almost any compiler released since 1998 should support it just fine.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading your compiler can be a mess. I wouldn't recommend it. I also wouldn't recommend teaching with such an outdated compiler.

Personally, I would go for one out of 2 approaches: install an old Linux version that comes with this Gcc version in a virtual machine or if it's a handful of files, use  [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

For virtualization, I only have experience with virtualbox, however other good alternatives exist. You search for a Linux distro that has that version of Gcc and install a temporary computer that way. Once the course is finished, you throw the machine out and your current system ain't affected.

The easier alternative is to simply plug your files in   [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/), it has a lot of different compiler versions including the compiler you need.

It does require you to enter file by file, so I would recommend writing a script to (recursively) resolve your local includes and create a simple preprocessed file that you can plug in the site.

For sure, write your code with a supported version of c++, don't use c++2a features when coding.