# How to check c++ version in microsoft visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to check the version of c++ i have with the following code.

```
if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
        else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
        else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
        else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
        else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
```

the output is C++98 version , but i am definitely able to use c++11 features so i think i am not getting the correct version from the code.

How can i check which version of c++ i am using ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

Comment: [You get the default 199711L](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2019) unless you explicitly set the `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler option

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536462/5517378) also... Especially the comments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/

> You need to compile with the `/Zc:__cplusplus` switch to see the updated value of the `__cplusplus` macro.

Note that this was added in MSVC 2017 (version 15.7 Preview 3), it's not available in older versions.

Answer (score 32):

Easier way to check it than writing a program is under
*Project (right-click your project name in solution explorer) > Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard*

And you can also change it there.

I know it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759740/14559107).

Comment: The point is to figure it out from a program, sometimes we need to use c++ from within a program.