# Best way to test for 1s-complement CPU in C++?

Tags: c++, ones-complement

I am doing some bit-fiddling that only works on a 2s-complement CPU. I would like to add a static_assert to the code, just in case. (Wikipedia [Ones' complement page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) says that only some Univac machines still use 1s-complement, but I want to be paranoid.)
Is this code bullet-proof, standard-conforming, and reasonable?

```
static_assert(~0 == -1, "2s-complement CPU required");
// note the tilde versus the minus sign
```

I do not have access to a 1s-complement machine. Is anyone with such willing to test this?

Comment: Should be noted that C++20 requires 2s complement.

Comment: Adding to previous comment, it is http://wg21.link/P0907

Comment: `static_assert(true, "2s-complement CPU required");` :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: yes, your condition `true` is correct for C++20, as @ChrisMM said, but  (a) I want a test that works for older versions; (b) if any 1s complement compiler still exists, it (by definition) is not C++20 compliant; (c) it seems `true` could be replaced by something like `__cplusplus >= 202000L` but it appears that older compilers do not consistently support `__cplusplus` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)