# Which header file or definitions to use for using char8_t data type in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

So I want to use `char8_t` data type in my code. But my compiler shows me that it could not find an identifier like `char8_t` , which probably means it could not find required header file or definitions for it.

So can anyone tell me what header files / definitions should I use to get the `char8_t` data type? The language is `C++`. I'll be thankful if you can also answer for `C`.

PS:`<cwchar>` did not work.

Edit:

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwchar>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char c='a';
wchar_t w=L'A';
char8_t c8=u8'c';
char16_t c16=u'D';
char32_t c32=U'K';

cout<<"Data Type"<<"\t"<<"Size"<<"\n"
<<"char"<<"\t \t"<<sizeof(c)<<" bytes"<<"\n"
<<"wchar_t"<<"\t \t"<<sizeof(w)<<" bytes"<<"\n"
<<"char8_t"<<"\t"<<sizeof(c8)<<"\n" 
<<"char16_t"<<"\t"<<sizeof(c16)<<" bytes"<<"\n"
<<"char32_t"<<"\t"<<sizeof(c32)<<" bytes"<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

My compiler throws this error:

```
WideCharacters.cpp: In function 'int main()':
WideCharacters.cpp:8:5: error: 'char8_t' was not declared in this 
scope; did you mean 'wchar_t'?
8 |     char8_t c8=u8'c';
  |     ^~~~~~~
  |     wchar_t
WideCharacters.cpp:15:31: error: 'c8' was not declared in this 
scope; did you mean 'c'?
15 |     <<"char8_t"<<"\t"<<sizeof(c8)<<"\n"
  |                               ^~
  |                               c
```

Edit-2:

I have my C++ standard set to C++20 in VS code so there is no problem with standard.

Comment: Can you post your code and the error message?

Comment: Ok please wait a minute.

Comment: You might need to enable C++20 mode when building. What compiler are you using? What version of it? What flags and options do you pass to the compiler when building?

Comment: Also note that all character types are *keywords* and thus don't need any specific header file to work.

Comment: I'm using mingw g++ 11.2.0 by msys project. I have also enabled C++ 20 standard in VS code.

Comment: @Zeph_The_Hungry_Loli The "enabled in VSC" part probably affects only the hints in the IDE (provided by VSC itself), not the actual compilation.

Comment: *How* have you "enabled C++20 in VS Code"? In what configuration file? And again, how do you build? What are the actual options and flags passed to the compiler?

Comment: I've changed the C++ standard to C++20 in the C/C++ extension settings. This  is the official extension by Microsoft.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh! I got it now. Is there anyway to automate compiler to C++20 instead of specifying it all time?

Comment: Since you use MinGW [this MinGW with VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) might be useful. Especially the section about the `tasks.json` file.

Comment: @Zeph_The_Hungry_Loli This depends on how you invoke the compiler.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude and HolyBlackCat. The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char8_t` is a keyword. It's built into the language, so you don't need any headers.

If it doesn't work, either your compiler doesn't support it, or you forgot to enable C++20 support (e.g. `-std=c++20` in GCC).

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is possibly the compiler is not able to identify that this is a `C++20` feature.

Compile using this:
`g++ -Wall -std=c++20 "yourFileName".cpp`

replace `youFileName` with that of the file name.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! It worked. But is there any way to automate this in VS code instead of typing each time? Like just running the code runner in VS code.

Comment: @Zeph_The_Hungry_Loli  Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100553/how-do-i-use-c20-in-vscode) help you?

Comment: I ran the code and It showed my C++ standard is C++17. Is there any way to change default standard to C++20? My compiler supports C++20.