# Visual C++ error, namespace "std" has no member "any"

Tags: visual-c++

[Here is the code preview in vs 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqqgz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::any` and `std::any_cast` were added in `c++17`, please make sure that you are compiling with the correct version.

Comment: yes now it works when I configure my cpp language standard to c++17, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to add an include to `<any>` to get my program to compile.  My includes look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
```

I also was able to confirm I was using the c++ 17 compiler by doing this:

```
   std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
    /*
see this on SO <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler>
C++ pre-C++98: __cplusplus is 1.
C++98: __cplusplus is 199711L.
C++98 + TR1: This reads as C++98 and there is no way to check that I know of.
C++11: __cplusplus is 201103L.
C++14: __cplusplus is 201402L.
C++17: __cplusplus is 201703L.
C++20: __cplusplus is 202002L.
    */
```