# clang compiling to which version of c++ in macOS?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
     if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
     else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
     else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
     else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
     else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";

     vector<int> a;
     a.push_back(3);
     vector<int> b = move(a);
    }
```

As far as I know, "move semantics" is a part of c++11

Output(when compiled with clang++ command without any flags):
C++98

Then how are the move semantics working??

I know that I can select the particular version of c++ I want to compile to with the -std=c++xx flag, but that's not what I want.

I want to know, what is the default version of c++ to which clang compiles to in macOS ?

Comment: You can check in code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132549/362589

Comment: The warning text would be nice. Along with version numbers. clang has compiled to C++14 for a good while. I know macOS hides what version they're actually using, but I haven't had this kind of issue.

Comment: @sweenish, I have updated the post. And if it is compiling to c++14 I don't think it should give the error I have shown in the image in my question.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that any project worth its salt will specify the C++ version to avoid these exact issues. Relying on the default is only a choice for toy programs.

Comment: @Dani, your link was very helpful. The default version my clang is compiling too is c++98, and the move() function is present in c++98 as well, but apparently it does not perform move semantics, but just deep copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default version my clang is compiling too is c++98, and the move() function is present in c++98 as well, but apparently it does not perform move semantics(i.e. create Rvalue Reference), but just deep copying.

The following link gives answer to finding out to which version of c++ the compiler is compiling to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132549/362589

Here is the link to the answer of what is move() in c++98 :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65010079/13023201

Answer (score 1):

clang has an option to specify the C++ version you want to use: - [std=xxx](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html).

Just like gcc, you can ask for the ISO or the GNU version. Eg:

```
c++98
c++03
ISO C++ 1998 with amendments
gnu++98
gnu++03
ISO C++ 1998 with amendments and GNU extensions
```

It seems like clang uses the GNU flavor by default:

> The default C++ language standard is gnu++14.

gcc does the same.

It is likely that you compiler uses gnu98 by default, which means your version of C++ is indeed C++98 (== C++03), but extensions provide additional features such as `std::move`.

You can go to [compiler explorer and test the following code](https://godbolt.org/z/EbWeT1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << __cplusplus;
}
```

Compiled with x86-64 clang 11.0.0 using `-std=gnu++98`, the program outputs:

> 199711

You can check from you code if the ISO or the GNU version if used thanks to the [**STRICT_ANSI** macro](https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html):

> Differences between all c* and gnu* modes:
>
> c* modes define “**STRICT_ANSI**”.
>
> (...)