# What is move() in c++98?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, c++98

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void){

 vector<int> a;
 a.push_back(3);
 vector<int> b = move(a);
 cout<<"b: "<<b.data()<<endl;
 cout<<"a: "<<a.data()<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Output (in c++98):

```
b: 0x7f9a82405730
a: 0x7f9a82405720
```

Output (in c++11):

```
b: 0x7f9a82405730
a: 0x0
```

I am using Apple clang 11.0.3.

No compiler flags are used for the first output.

`-std=c++11` flag for the second output.

I know what move() does in c++11 (and higher versions).
But as I can see using move() in c++98 does nothing to the object passed and just deep copy happens.

Then why is there a move() in c++98??

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225132/discussion-on-question-by-ritobroto-ganguly-what-is-move-in-c98).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that you can call `std::move` at all pre-C++11 is that libc++ doesn't wrap [its implementation of it](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/6d3b81664a4b79b32ed2c2f46b21ab0dca9029cc/libcxx/include/type_traits#L2613-L2622) in `#if _LIBCPP_STD_VER >= 11`. This doesn't work in libstdc++ (which Linux uses by default) because [it guards `std::move` with `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/b85fb3187e4fa591839b5292756bfadbed9761ba/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/move.h#L52-L102).

As for why using it doesn't make `a.data()` be null, it's because libc++ [does wrap the move constructor in `#ifndef _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/6d3b81664a4b79b32ed2c2f46b21ab0dca9029cc/libcxx/include/vector#L1278-L1298), so it falls back to the copy constructor.

Comment: Maybe interesting to note is that libc++ has always targetted c++11 and above and c++98 was added afterwards because some people needed it.

Comment: Might also be useful to note that there is no `move()` in C++98 (outside of `char_traits<T>::move()`)