# Heap allocations in string class in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, move, swap

In the following C++ code, there should be three heap allocations as in the `swap()` function one temporary string object is also created. Why there are only two heap allocations in this code?

### Without using move semantics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;


static uint32_t allocations = 0;

void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    allocations++;
    cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes\n";
    return malloc(size);
}


void swapUsingMove(string& arg1, string& arg2)
{
    string temp = arg1;
    arg1 = arg2;
    arg2 = temp;
    cout << allocations << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string str1{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    string str2{"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"};

    swapUsingMove(str1, str2);
    cout << str1 << " " << str2;
    return 0;
}
```

> Output
>
> ```
> Allocating 51 bytes
> Allocating 51 bytes
> 2
> ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
> ```

### By using move semantics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;


static uint32_t allocations = 0;

void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    allocations++;
    cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes\n";
    return malloc(size);
}


void swapUsingMove(string& arg1, string& arg2)
{
    string temp = move(arg1);
    arg1 = move(arg2);
    arg2 = move(temp);
    cout << allocations << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string str1{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    string str2{"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"};

    swapUsingMove(str1, str2);
    cout << str1 << " " << str2;
    return 0;
}
```

> Output
>
> ```
> Allocating 51 bytes
> Allocating 51 bytes
> 2
> ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
> ```

Even without using the move semantics, why there are only two heap allocations? Where does the temp string gets allocated memory? If there are two heap allocations in both the cases then what is the advantage of using std:: move() here?

Comment: Can you please show us the program you actually have trouble understanding ("without using the move semantics")? Also include the actual output you get from the program, and possibly the expected output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring/10319672#10319672

Comment: @jtbandes This one is not about SSO, don't mislead.

Comment: fwiw, this is a much simpler example of getting less allocations than there are strings https://godbolt.org/z/h6r3sr. What you mean with "Even wihtout using the move semantics" is not quite clear

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you please now again go through the question? Or should I edit it again?

Comment: what compiler are you using ? For the first I get different output with gcc and clang (both with optimizations enabled)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am using GCC with optimizations disabled

Comment: Have you looked at the generated code to see what it does? Perhaps the compiler recognizes the "swap" pattern and generates code to swap the pointers instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What I don't understand is that why there is not any heap allocation for the string temp? How is arg1 being assigned to temp without heap allocation?

Comment: Check if your `string` implementation can share the same string (similar to `shared_ptr`). For this just add the third string `string str3(str1);`.

Comment: @ArunSuryan: What version of GCC, and what command line are you using for the compile? I can't reproduce on a [simple test cases with Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oG6T93); I get three allocations (though they're much smaller; 27 bytes, not 51).

Comment: There are [multiple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) `operator new` functions, including array versions. Perhaps one of the other functions is being called.

Comment: @Red.Wave Copy on write is not permitted since C++11.

Comment: One possible optimization is copy-on-write. You need to reimplement `operator delete` as well. U'r most probably using an outdated tool chain - in case of COW on `std::string`.

Comment: @DanielLangr I see, but looks most probable. Although more aggressive automatic optimizations might be in charge.

Comment: @Red.Wave It seems that you are right: https://godbolt.org/z/rP7M77. In that case, the question shouldn't be tagged with C++11.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Of course. I tested with `-std=c++17`, then noticed the tag and tried `-std=c++11`. Of course the tag would be a lie. How did they use `std::move` pre-C++11 though?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: C++11 was supposed to be C++08, and many C++23 pending features were already under the radar back then. The tool chain might've partially supported C++11. I'm not sure about the publication date of rvalue ref proposal though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger for `std::move` pre C++11 @ clang there was a question recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009198/what-is-move-in-c98

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using an implementation that behaves according to the C++98/03 standard and that implements *copy-on-write* for `std::string`.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rP7M77

If this is the case, your question should not be tagged with `c++11`, since copy-on-write is not permitted since then. (SSO is usually implemented instead, but this is a different story.)

If you switch to a newer GCC, you will see 3 allocations: https://godbolt.org/z/b5q1MM

Comment: So there will be three allocations in both the cases or only the case where I am using move semantics?

Comment: @ArunSuryan Could you please answer the question from the comments about what GCC version? Plus which compilation flags do you use? Anyway, it seems to be some partial C++11 support. COW is not allowed in C++11, and `std::move` did not exist until C++11. According to the C++ standards, you shouldn't be able to use both.

Comment: it's gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)

Comment: @ArunSuryan Why there should be 3 allocations with move semantics? Move just "steals" resources, i.e., the stored string. Why should it allocate anything?

Comment: @ArunSuryan And yes, it seems that GCC 4.8.5 mixes COW and `std::move` features, which does not correspond with any particular C++ standard. I would suggest you not to use such an outdated version.