# How can I define an executable that has different compiler command-line arguments?

Tags: meson-build

I have a C++ project and I want to test the compatibility of library headers with different compiler versions.  I have a simple source file (that includes said headers) and I want to change the compiler argument to `std=gnu++11` for this one target.  How do I do that?

```
executable('old_compiler_test', ['octest.cxx']
    # override ARGS here ??? how
)
```

Note that I have

```
add_global_arguments(
    ['-std=gnu++17',
    ....
```

rather than the dedicated option for this, in spite of the warning to prefer the special option, because the special option simply doesn't work.  (Why is a question I've never tracked down)

## update

To clarify:  I'm not trying to make additional configurations in the same way that debug and release are configurations.  I want a different compiler argument to be applied to a single target within the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From the Meson [documentation](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#executable), you can use the argument `<languagename>_args` to pass additional compiler arguments. In your case, since you use C++, it would give something like

```
executable('old_compiler_test', ['octest.cxx'],
    cpp_args: ['std=gnu++11']
)
```

However the documentation also specify that [there are no way to disable an argument added by `add_global_argument()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#add_global_arguments), so you will end up with both `-std=gnu++17` and `-std=gnu++11` passed to the compiler. I don't know how your compiler will behave, but I tried to pass both arguments to GCC 10.2 and it uses c++17 (not what you want).

#### Workaround

It seems that if you define the C++ version in the `project()` statement, Meson will removes it if an other version is specified in compiler arguments, giving the behaviour you expect.

Here is the sample I used:

`meson.build`

```
project('project-name', 'cpp',
   default_options: ['cpp_std=c++17']
)

executable('old_compiler_test', ['octest.cxx'],
    cpp_args: ['-std=gnu++11']
)
```

`octest.cxx`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
}
```

After compilation, running the executable will print `201103`, [which means that the compiler used c++11 as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132549/13272497).