# Is there a way to determine the value of the `gcc -std=` flag inside the source code?

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

Does `gcc` define a `macro` or something else, when I use the `-std=c++zz` flag? Imagine, that I have a (nice and easy and fast and...) solution in my program which only works with `g++ -std=c++20`. However I want to provide a (less better but working) solution which works with `-std=c++11` or something else. For example:

```
#ifdef __STD20__
#include <numbers>
const double PI=std::numbers::pi;
#else
const double PI=4.0*atan(1);
#endif
```

Or should I handle it somehow in the `makefile`? Thank you for your advice.

(**NOTE:** the question is not about defining pi; it is just the shortest example I could provide.)

Comment: I believe the marked duplicate answers your question, if it does not, please let me know.

Comment: I've reopened this because "C++ version" is not the correct way of checking for modern features, which have associated test macros.

Comment: In this case you can use `#ifdef __cpp_lib_math_constants`

Comment: ...preceded by `#if __has_include(<version>)` `#include <version>`.

Comment: OP, what feature your actual code uses? Surely not `<numbers>`?

Comment: I think you are better off testing individual features of C++ see [feature test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, it have turned out, that my question is a duplicate. My original intention was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658 (but I couldn't find it before post my question.) However, the individual `feature test` that have been suggested in your comments and during the second closure is a better solution. Inspired by this [meta anwser](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297547/6113363) I wouldn't remove the question, to help the ones like me. Thank you again.