fatal error: include/chrono: No such file or directory 14 | #include <chrono>
I'm trying to build https://github.com/eunomia-bpf/bpftime/
When I use #include <chrono>, It gives the following error:
fatal error: include/chrono: No such file or directory    14 | #include <chrono>

Compiler Versions:
pegasus@pegasus:~$ clang --version
clang version 19.0.0git (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 815644b4dd882ade2e5649d4f97c3dd6f7aea200)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/build/bin
pegasus@pegasus:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

pegasus@pegasus:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

The Makefile. It invokes the cmake command. I'm running it from inside bpftime repository.
.PHONY: install coverage test docs help build clean unit-test-daemon unit-test unit-test-runtime
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

define BROWSER_PYSCRIPT
import os, webbrowser, sys

try:
    from urllib import pathname2url
except:
    from urllib.request import pathname2url

webbrowser.open("file://" + pathname2url(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])))
endef
export BROWSER_PYSCRIPT

define PRINT_HELP_PYSCRIPT
import re, sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    match = re.match(r'^([a-zA-Z\d_-]+):.*?## (.*)$$', line)
    if match:
        target, help = match.groups()
        print("%-20s %s" % (target, help))
endef
export PRINT_HELP_PYSCRIPT

BROWSER := python3 -c "$$BROWSER_PYSCRIPT"
INSTALL_LOCATION := ~/.local
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
JOBS := 1

help:
    @python3 -c "$$PRINT_HELP_PYSCRIPT" < $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

build-unit-test:
    cmake -Bbuild  -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_UNIT_TESTING=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
    cmake --build build --config Debug --target bpftime_runtime_tests bpftime_daemon_tests  -j$(JOBS)

unit-test-daemon: 
    ./build/daemon/test/bpftime_daemon_tests

unit-test-runtime:
    make -C runtime/test/bpf && cp runtime/test/bpf/*.bpf.o build/runtime/test/
    ./build/runtime/unit-test/bpftime_runtime_tests
    cd build/runtime/test && make && ctest -VV

unit-test: unit-test-daemon unit-test-runtime ## run catch2 unit tests

build: ## build the package with test and all components
    cmake -Bbuild -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_UNIT_TESTING=1 -DBUILD_BPFTIME_DAEMON=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
    cmake --build build --config Debug  -j$(JOBS)

build-iouring: ## build the package with iouring extension
    cmake -Bbuild -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_IOURING_EXT=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo
    cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo  -j$(JOBS)

release: ## build the release version
    cmake -Bbuild  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo \
                   -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_INFO
    cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo --target install  -j$(JOBS)

release-with-llvm-jit: ## build the package, with llvm-jit
    cmake -Bbuild  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo \
                   -DBPFTIME_LLVM_JIT=1
    cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo --target install -j$(JOBS)

build-vm: ## build only the core library
    make -C vm build

build-llvm: ## build with llvm as jit backend
    cmake -Bbuild   -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_UNIT_TESTING=1 \
                    -DBPFTIME_LLVM_JIT=1 \
                    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
    cmake --build build --config Debug -j$(JOBS)

clean: ## clean the project
    rm -rf build
    make -C runtime clean
    make -C vm clean

install: release ## Invoke cmake to install..


The I'm using to build the project:
make release JOBS=$(nproc)

Well, since it can't find the file, and from the looks of it you've installed that library into /usr/local, there's a good chance that you'll have to tell the compiler to look for header files there too. Probably something like -I/usr/local...

Hmmmm. What if I'm interpreting this wrong and bpftime is really after C++'s Chrono library and not this other chrono thing?

@user4581301 my bad. Yes you are correct. So how can I use #include ?

<chrono> should come stock with any C++ compiler that supports C++11 or a more recent Standard revision. Any way you can force the build script to show you the command line?

I've added my compiler versions.
I also didn't understand what you meant by Any way you can force the build script to show you the command line?

Apologies. Are you typing cmake ... and can add the --verbose option or are you running cmake to set up the build and then building with make and can add VERBOSE=1 to the invocation?

Groovy and thanks. I'll have to bow out on this one. First time I've seen make calling cmake. Usually it's the other way around. Not sure where I'd put the request for verbose output.

Go here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536462/4013258 and add these lines to your main and look at compiler output what it says.

I figured it out. I was importing it wrong. Since chrono is a cpp library, I was using importing it in c code also.

I figured it out. I was importing it wrong. Since chrono is a cpp library, I was using importing it in c code also.
