Changing options for different objects
I have a program that contain multiple views. Some views contain different objects by themselves, and some just display data in a table-like manner.
All of these views, and the objects some are displaying, have different options.
What I have right now is the following:
I have a dialog class that presents different tabs for every single object/view to display/change the options. I have the different handler classes that I used as a pointers to pass the options down to the properties dialog.
What I'd like to do is pass the view/object into the handler class in order to change the options.
I thought about using templates, but then realized I can't really do that since every view/object class has different options and so applying them will depend on the object itself.
And using is_same will actually defeats the purpose of templates.
What would be the better solution for that?
Some code:
std::unique_ptr<PropertiesHandler> propertiesPtr;
#if __cplusplus > 201300
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Handler>( m_conf->m_dbOptions, m_canvas );
#else
    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Handler>( new Handler( m_conf->m_dbOptions, m_canvas ) );
#endif
    propertiesPtr = std::move( ptr );
    propertiesPtr->SetType( m_type == View ? ViewProperties : ObjectProperties );

That's how I pass the options down to the properties dialog.
EDIT:
In the properties dialog, I have the following code:
auto type = handler->GetType() )
switch( type )
{
    case ViewProperties:
        Handler *propHandler = dynamic_cast<>( handler );
        // create pages relevant for the view 1
}


question is not clear at all, consider adding code on how the view uses these options, also you might want to look into double dispatch and Acyclic Visitor pattern.

[OT] You might create your own make_unique to avoid to have to check version at each time.

Too many things are unclear/implied in this question. Create a compliable example in Compiler Explorer containing only relevant details.

@jarod42 or just not use it at all, since it doubles the testing effort -- he has to compile with an "old" and a "new" compiler. I generally consider it the better choice to just stick with the minimum requirement. While a careful look at the code and just compiling it twice might suffice here, I suspect he might be doing similar things in other places too...

@AhmedAEK, as an example - some views might be setting the background colors, while others might be changing the font. The objects are the easiest ones as they are only changing the internal options Some options can include the X,Y positions. Some views can have options of what object to display. Everything is different.

@Gene, which one is unclear? I can clear it up for you...

@Gene, you could also check the edit I just made...

Handler *propHandler = dynamic_cast<>( handler ) - this does not look like C++11, the used tag [tag:c++11] is wrong and #if __cplusplus > 201300 is a futile check, always true.

@3CxEZiVlQ, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler, that check is correct. I'm using different machine with the different compilers which have different standard y default.

Reflection is the standard solution to this problem.
Objects have properties.  These properties can be inspected at runtime by other objects via some kind of reflection mechanism.
Views in turn both have properties, and can modify which properties of the objects they are containing are exposed (and how).
Once you have the properties of the view (and the filters properties of the objects), you then use data-driven design to populate the properties dialog.
The structure of the properties and what exactly you expose becomes sort of key here.  Like, exposing two properties "x" and "y" as numbers is one thing - exposing those two properties as siblings of a sub-property called "location" is another.  And tagging the "location" sub-property with meta-information saying it is a coordinate is yet more detail.
In the properties dialog, when you see a sub-property tagged as a coordinate, you can spawn a pair of x/y spin boxes, and maybe even a crosshair control that lets you pick a location.
You either end up adding meta-information at the property level, or you teach the property dialog to use custom layouts (via some data) for each kind of view/object.  The first is more code, the second more UX work.
Core to both cases, however, is that you do not hand-write C++ that decides the exact location where each control exists and what the text is.  You really want UX like this to be data-driven, either directly from the reflection or from some non-C++ layout language.  (I suppose a ASL would do)
This is because deciding where the X and Y widget goes is not something that is anywhere near needing the performance levels that justifies "and if you make a typo, the program crashes on new moon mondays", which is what C++ is.

agreed, it can be solved via reflection. I would like to suggest to checkout this c++ reflection library, which might help you to achive the same-
https://github.com/ReflectCxx/ReflectionTemplateLibrary-CPP
